# RVEST - Extracting text from table - Problems with access to the right table

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to extract the values in the table on the top right side of this Webpage:

https://www.timeanddate.de/wetter/deutschland/karlsruhe/klima

(Wärmster Monat : VALUE, Kältester Monat: VALUE, Jahresniederschlag: VALUE)

Unfortunately, if I use html_nodes("Selectorgadgets result for the specific value"), I receive the values for the table on the top of the link:

https://www.timeanddate.de/stadt/info/deutschland/karlsruhe

(The webpages are similar, if you click "Uhrzeit/Übersicht" on the top bar, you access the second page and table, if you click "Wetter" --> "Klima", you access the first page/table (the one I want to extract values from!)

```
 num_link= "https://www.timeanddate.de/wetter/deutschland/Karlsruhe/klima"


  num_page= read_html(num_link)


  rain_year = num_page %>% html_nodes("#climateTable > div.climate-month.climate-month--allyear > div:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()

  temp_warm = num_page %>% html_nodes("#climateTable > div.climate-month.climate-month--allyear > div:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()

  temp_cold = num_page %>% html_nodes("#climateTable > div.climate-month.climate-month--allyear > div:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
```

I get " character (empty) " for each variable . :(

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: I am confused as it seems you are saying you do and you do not want the top right table. Did you want the top table or the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `html_table` function in rvest, which is pretty good by now. Makes it a bit easier to extract, but I do recommend learning to identify the right css-selectors as well, as it does not always work. `html_table` always returns a list with all tables from the webpage, so in this case the steps are:

1. get the html
2. get the tables
3. index the right table (here there is only one)
4. reformat a little to extract the values

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)


result <- read_html("https://www.timeanddate.de/wetter/deutschland/karlsruhe/klima") %>%  
  html_table() %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
 rename('measurement' = 1,
        'original' = 2) %>% 
  mutate(value_num = str_extract_all(original,"[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*") %>% unlist())
```